# What Windows 7 Product Keys will work for Bootcamp!

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I am trying to setup Bootcamp, but am having a tough time. I know this question has been asked previously, but all of the answers are outdated. What SKU product key for Windows 7 is licensed for Bootcanp on 2013 MacBook Pro?

Keep in mind I don't have a DVD drive which makes use of any optical media problematic.

Comment: Isn't the point of StackExchange to be able to improve on old/outdated questions and answers, rather than re-asking ad infinitum?

Answer (score 5):

At least the following versions of Windows 7 will work find on bootcamp.

- Home Premium
- Professional
- Ultimate

all work. In order to obtain a key for one of these versions, You will need to find an ISO and a Matching Product Key *for the same version of windows*.

Microsoft offer downloads of Windows 8 from the [Microsoft Store](http://www.microsoftstore.com/). If you're set on Windows 7, then your options are limited.

1. If you have a MSDN account, you can download an MSDN ISO from there.
2. You can purchase Windows 7 from a reseller (Amazon, NewEgg, ) and borrow a USB optical drive to use a retail CD/DVD.
3. Download the Relevant ISO directly here (Content hosted on Digital River), and then use the [Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool](http://images2.store.microsoft.com/prod/clustera/framework/w7udt/1.0/en-us/Windows7-USB-DVD-tool.exe) to install.

   - [Home Premium SP1 (English, 64-bit)](http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-58997.iso)
   - [Professional SP1 (English, 64-bit)](http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59186.iso)
   - [Ultimate SP1 (English, 64-bit)](http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59465.iso)
   - [Home Premium SP1 (English, 32-bit)](http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-58996.iso)
   - [Professional SP1 (English, 32-bit)](http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59183.iso)
   - [Ultimate SP1 (English, 32-bit)](http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59463.iso)

I'd wager that each of these methods would work for Windows 8, except the direct downloads, which link to Windows 7 only.

Comment: WHere in the store are downloads of Windows 8 whoich are not upgrades from Vista/Windows 7?

Comment: Sign in to your Microsoft Store account using your Microsoft account and password.
In the right-hand menu, click Downloads, Product Keys, and Subscriptions.
On the Downloads, Product Keys and Subscriptions page, find the Windows product that you purchased. Select the download option (32-bit or 64-bit) and file type ISO

Comment: The question is more which product do I buy and where is that on the store?

Comment: Just go to the purchase screen, and make sure *download* is selected. http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/mseea/en_IE/pdp/Windows-8/productID.275219500

Comment: The question specifically stipulates that I do not have access to an optical drive.

Comment: Please also provide direct links, for instance to the Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool

Comment: I wanted to provide a comprehensive answer, which other people may find useful, too. Also, you just said it would be 'problematic' and therefore I didn't rule out borrowing of an optical drive. The Windows 7 USB/DVD Download tool link has now been fixed.

Comment: I find this answer really lacking. You can also get a Product Key from go2keys.com, for much cheaper. All of the sites you mention only sell DVDs, rather than just keys

Comment: Sincerest apologies for not listing all possible websites which sell Product Keys for Microsoft products. I wanted to list the most genuine and simplest instructions which answer your question. Also, DVD's come with keys.